# React native tab stack not returning to root stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have stack, the first screen on the stack is a screen with a bottom menu and another stack which contains The screens to show on click of menu item. When I click or navigate from this stack, it tries to load the screen on the same page but the screen I want to navigate on the root stack. This implwmentation is to get the full screen view for the screens except the base screen when tapping the menu item. Any help??

Comment: please provide a snippet of your code for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:
Does your routes structure look like this?

- Root (Stack Navigator)

  - Menu (Screen)
  - Views (Stack Navigator)

    ```
    - Screen 1
    - Screen 2
    - ...
    - Screen N
    ```

Or did you put a Stack Navigator INSIDE the “Menu” view? 
If so, I recommend you to separate navigators from the views, so you can have more control over the nesting levels.

If you want to have a main view that acts as a menu (something like the Drawer Navigator behaviour), and when you press on a menu item get redirected to another view (without the menu on bottom), you can use only one stack navigator, containing the menu screen and the rest of the screens in the same level.

It should look like this:

- stack navigator

  - menu screen (with buttons that navigate to the rest of the views)
  - screen 1
  - screen 2
  - ...
  - screen N

Then, you only have to add the routes to the navigator and call `this.props.navigation.navigate(“ScreenN”)` on each menu button.

Comment: Yup, I do have a stack navigator inside the menu screen to switcj the screens on click of menu item.

Comment: The stacks are like this. 
stack1{ 
screen1:menuscreen,
screen2:signin,
screen3:login,
screen4:page1,
...}
menuscreenn.js
return(
<stack2>
<menuwitt 4 tabs>
)
stack2:{
screen1:tabscreen1,
screen2:tabscreen2,
screen3:tabscreen3,
screen4:tabscreen4
}
  I am navigating from screen4 from the stack2 to the screen 4 in the stack1, so that i should get the full view of the page 1.

Comment: @DinilAt have you tried with the structure I purposed? I think it's better to keep your stack components separated from your other screens and use them just as routers and wrappers.

Comment: I tried but in that case, how i will be able to show the base screen while on click on the menu item.. ,for the base screens menu tab will be shown. I should use a stack inside the main screen.